# How to provide docker image tag dynamically to docker-compose.yml in Azure Release Pipeline Task?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have `docker-compose.yml` file present in the repository. I have added the image attribute in one of the services to pull the docker images. I have not hard coded the docker image and docker tag and planning to pass these arguments at the runtime to `docker-compose.yml` file.

How to pass the runtime arguments like `IMAGE_TAG=82`, `IMAGE_NAME=app1` to the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables in the docker-compose file for the image & tag:

```
version: '3'
services:
    redis-server:
       image: ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}
```

And pass the arguments in the docker-compose task:

[image]

You can also define pipeline variables and check the "Settable at release time":

[image]

So when you click on "Create Release" you can replace the values:

[image]

Comment: I'm using "Azure Web App for Containers" run task for my release pipeline. I added the key/value pairs in pipeline variables but the docker-compose.yml file didn't pick these values.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS I don't use this task so I don't know :/

Comment: No problem. I tried with other task `DockerComposeTask` and it is working.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS Great! You can accept the answer :)